# Cleverref shows extra question sign in Latex

Tags: latex, pdflatex, tex, xelatex

There are two extra question signs when I use cleveref package. How can I remove them?
when I reference to two labels:
here is the output:

?? 16 ?? 15

I'm compiling using Xelatex. I've prepared a minimal to compile ro reproduce the error:

```
minimal to compile:
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[inlinemathdigits=persian,displaymathdigits=persian]{xepersian}
%\setdigitfont{PGaramanod}
\settextfont{XB-Niloofar.ttf}
\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref}
%\newcommand\crefrangeconjunction{\textendash}

\begin{questions}
\pointpoints{نمره}{نمره}
\section*{بخش اول: سوالات تشریحی}



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\question \label{D1}
با در نظر گرفتن ارتباطات رادیویی موبایل، موارد زیر را شرح می دهد: 
\cref{D2,D3,D4}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item CDMA
    \item TDD
    \item Full Duplex System
\end{enumerate}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\question \label{D2}
تکامل سیستم رادیویی تلفن همراه از نسل اول به نسل سوم از نظر باند فرکانس ، میزان داده و کاربردها توصیف کنید


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\question \label{D3}
برای یک شبکه محلی بی سیم (WLAN) خاص با یک نمودار توضیح دهید که  چگونه می توان برای چهار نقطه دسترسی دریک منطقه داده شده با حداقل همپوشانی کانال ایجاد کرد.

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\question \label{D4}
مقایسه ای بین WLAN و WiMax از نظر دامنه ، توان ،ht و کاربردها انجام دهید


\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that there is no predefined translation for `question` into Persian.

You can add it like this (I don't speak Persian, so I just used a random word from your example instead, replace it with something appropriate)

```
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[inlinemathdigits=persian,displaymathdigits=persian]{xepersian}
\settextfont{Arial}
\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref}

\crefname{question}{‌نمره}{‌نمره} % singular + plural for question
\newcommand{\crefrangeconjunction}{نمره} % to
\newcommand{\crefpairconjunction}{نمره} % and

\begin{document}
\cref{D2,D3,D4}


\begin{questions}
\question \label{D1}
\question \label{D2}
\question \label{D3}
\question \label{D4}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```